# While loop - time of exit

Tags: while-loop

This question applies I suppose to programming in general, but my application is built in MATLAB (based on C++):

In a while loop, if the while condition is no longer satisfied, does the loop run to its completion or does it exit at the exact moment that the conditions of the while loop are no longer satisfied?

e.g.

```
x = 1
while (x = 1)
{
   x = 0
   (some code)
}
```

In this case, does (some code) run?

PS. I know the syntax is terrible, it's just to illustrate the situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It runs to completion. The while is only considered at entry to the loop block. So yes, (some code) does run.

Answer (score 0):

it will only check at the entry of loop block. If it satisfies the condition, then it will run to completion, of course you can always choose to break the loop, if not then it will not enter the loop at all.